# Adjusting PDF restrictions with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, permissions, restrictions

I have a user uploading a PDF to my server, is it possible to adjust the PDF restrictions via PHP to not allow printing, copying, etc?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will meet your needs.

http://www.idsecuritysuite.com/blog/password-protect-a-pdf-document-in-php

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi-protection-128/downloads/

Alternatively you could adjust the permissions of the PDF after upload:

```
chmod("/dir/file.pdf", 0600);
```

However this will mean users cannot read the file, which i don't believe is the desired effect your after.